# Find correlation between different wind direction with aerosol

Tags: regression, correlation, python, circular-statistics

I have wind direction and aerosol data. I want to find correlation between different wind direction (like: corr between N-E/aerosol, E-S/aerosol, S-W/aerosol and W-N/aerosol). wind direction data are in 0-360 degree. Is there anyways to find correlation in such a way:

I have also included my datasets here:
[sample_data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2rkXkOkG7ExZUU1MmFJdmM1YjA)

Your help will be highly appriciated.

Comment: Because you tagged your question both with "regression" and "correlation," please clarify what you are looking for.  What would "correlation" mean in this application?

Answer (score 1):

The special thing with circular data is that 0 and 360 degrees are the same, although numerically far away. Thus, using ordinary correlation coefficients would not be appropriate.

The rich field of circular statistics has come up with one or the other correlation coefficient, see e.g. [1] or the book of Jammalamadaka and Gupta [2] with a whole chapter on correlations of angular data.

[1] N. Fisher & A. Lee (1983). A correlation coefficient for circular data. Biometrika. 70 (2), 327-332. DOI: 10.1093/biomet/70.2.327

[2] S. Rao Jammalamadaka, Ambar Sengupta. Topics in Circular Statistics. World Scientific, 2001